# How to enable right click mouse in gvim?

Tags: gvim, mouse

I can use right click mouse in vim. It can't be used in my gvim. How to enable right click mouse in gvim?

Comment: Do you have popup menu on right click when `gvim -Nu NONE`?

Answer (score 1):

First see if your mouse works at all (`:help 'mouse'`, `:set mouse?`).

Then see what the right button is supposed to do (`:help 'mousemodel'`, `:set mousemodel?`). Maybe it works, but not the way you expect.